# Kafka Error serializing Avro message Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

Im trying out Kafka streams, managed to stream normal string from one topic to another, but now i want to serialize it as AVRO message. Ive looked around the internet for a solution but i didnt find one so this is kinda my last hope. This is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://url:9092";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "TestAvro222");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, url);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        //props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
        props.put("schema.registry.url", url);


        final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
                url);
        final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream
                ("topic1",
                        Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));
        File file = new File("urltoschema");
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(file);
        KTable<String, GenericRecord> textLines_table = textLines.mapValues(value -> avroMaker(schema, value)).toTable();
        //KTable textLines_table = textLines.toTable();
        textLines_table.toStream().to("TEST-AVRO22", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
    }
```

When i run it i get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Error encountered sending record to topic TEST-AVRO22 for task 0_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource$KTableSourceProcessor.process(KTableSource.java:152)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:809)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1296)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:63)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer.serialize(GenericAvroSerializer.java:39)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:157)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:787)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:722)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:896)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:722)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:294)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:384)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:561)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:549)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:290)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:397)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:376)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:364)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.register(SchemaRegistryClient.java:51)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:70)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

No idea whats wrong, and ive searched multiple websites to find a solution, to no avail. please help

Comment: Hi!  have you checked if schema registry is reachable from browser? ex try to list subjects:`http://url:9092/subjects`

Comment: I have lenses.io, its url is http://url:9991, and i can go see the schema registry fine at  http://url:9991/data/schemas

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I figured out my schema registry has a different url than the one i provided in the code, so that fixed it